# Jquery not detecting my change event on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little bit confused. I am trying to add a `change` event to a `text`.

This is my `html`:

```
<input type="text" id="tag_search" placeholder="Start typing to search tags..." name="tag_search" size="33"/>
```

This is my `script`

```
$("#tag_search").change(function(){
    alert('Typing');
});
```

I'm aware that the `change` event will only fire once the input element loses focus but even when I do that the alert does not display.

but it will not work at all. Can anyone help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a4b4oyvq/ -- Your problem isn't reproducible. Are you aware that the `change` event only fires when the element loses focus?

Comment: DOM is not ready probably. Try: `$(function() { $('#tab_search').change(...); })`

Comment: change on text input fires when you leave the input. insted try with `input`

Comment: You're code is correct, which means there is something else on your site breaking the code. Have a look in the console of your developer tool for errors.

Comment: @George You forgot that jsFiddle runs any js on load by default while on your html page you have to specify it yourself :)

Comment: @nicael I didn't forget -- I wrongly assumed the OP would know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should be

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $("#tag_search").change(function(){
        alert('Typing');
    });
})
```

It should be run on load.